# Passing complex data to REST WCF POST method

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm doing a WCF REST Service that needs to receive complex data through a client. I know I can't pass complex data through GET method, so I'm using a POST in order to send it.

I have the method definition like this...

```
[WebInvoke (UriTemplate="/test/item", Method="POST", 
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [OperationContract]
    string TestMethod(InItem item);
```

And I'm trying to consume like this with a .Net console client...

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myIP:port/test/item");
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Method = "POST";

InItem item = new InItem()
{
    Quantity = 2,
    BougthQuantity = 2,
    Code = "9998",
    Date = DataTime.Now
};

string itemToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(itemToSend);
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/json;";

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
stream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

But when I invoke the service method the 'item' parameter on TestMethod is always null, did I miss something or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Perhaps because when you serialise this to JSON and then stick it into your request stream, you're not actually passing an item, just an anonymous JSON object.Try wrapping it:
itemToSend="{item: "+JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)+"}"; 
I could be totally wrong though :()

Comment: Are these both using the same version of the library for InItem?

Comment: Also is InItem marked with the Serializable Attribute?

Comment: @RyanBennett the only serializer requiring `Serializable` is the `BinaryFormatter`. No need for it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answers, I just realize what the mistake is, first of all... Or course we can use the statement

```
"{\"item\":"+serialized object + "}"
```

but it's kind of messy, we can change BodyStyle to Bare.

Next, I was using the same library since the entity shares through projects and also I applied ContractSerializer to the entity...

The mistake was about the serialization of a "DateTime" parameter, since jsonSerializer using Newtonsoft serializer and DataContractJsonSerializer use a format of this kind

Date=2013-01-21T14:29:41.2211548-06:00 (Shown on fiddler)

So, I just change Datetime for string and it works fine...